# Azure MFA on premisse webapp

Tags: c#, azure, webforms, multi-factor-authentication

I have a webApplication (webforms) in my domain, authenticated through Active Directory, now I want in a determinate action in a form ask for a second authentication method like Microsoft MFA. ¿Is this  possible?.

My active directory is syncronized with Azure AD (because Office 365).

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a fairly broad question. Have you actually tried to solve this yourself? If so, mind you explaining what you tried, and maybe show some code that isn't working? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I only find code for use it with Windows.Identity, My idea is to ask for this "second factor autentication" before signing a document.

Answer (score 0):

Your on-premises Active Directory is synchronized with Azure AD. For all the directly cloud only apps you will avail MFA directly either by CA policies or enabling at the user level.

In order to have MFA for on-premises application you can configure Azure Application Proxy with AAD Pre-authentication and implement MFA via Azure MFA service. You can also leverage Conditional Access , Azure MFA and Azure AD Identity protection for this purpose as well.

I would recommend you to go through this two [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy) in order to get more detail about [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy) AD application proxy.